# dpkg-buildpackage: dpkg-source -b zaptracker_1.0.0 gave error exit status 2 Unmet build dependencies: qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev- tools qt5-qmake

Tags: debian, package

I have problem with building Debian Package, Please help :

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-
 tools qt5-qmake
 W: Unmet build-dependency in source
 dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
 dpkg-buildpackage: source package zaptracker
 dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.0.0-1
 dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
 dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Satwinder Singh 
 <satwindersingh@zapbuild.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build zaptracker_1.0.0
 dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-
 tools qt5-qmake
 dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; 
 aborting
 dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
 dpkg-buildpackage: warning: this is currently a non-fatal warning with -
 S, but will probably become fatal in the future
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
 dh clean
 dh_testdir
 dh_auto_clean
 dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b zaptracker_1.0.0
 dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
 dpkg-source: info: building zaptracker using existing . 
 /zaptracker_1.0.0.orig.tar.gz
 dpkg-source: info: local changes detected, the modified files are:
 zaptracker_1.0.0/zaptracker.pro
 dpkg-source: error: aborting due to unexpected upstream changes, see 
 /tmp/zaptracker_1.0.0-1.diff.R7BNQV
 dpkg-source: info: you can integrate the local changes with dpkg-source -
 -commit
 dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b zaptracker_1.0.0 gave error exit 
 status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to satisify your build dependencies:

`apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qt5-qmake`